# How do I evaluate a command in CMakeLists.txt on Windows?

Tags: makefile, cmake, llvm

I want to set some variables in CMakeLists.txt, like `CMAKE_CXX__FLAGS`.

Unfortunately, I don't want to copy paste from terminal into `set()`.

Instead, I want to evaluate commands in CMakeLists.txt and set variables to their output.

An example is the following attempt:

```
set(x ${llvm-config --libs core})

message("${x}")
```

I want to bind the output of `llvm-config --libs core` to `x`. But evaluating this CMakeLists.txt results in output: `${llvm-config;--libs;core}`.

What is the proper way to evaluate commands in CMakeLists.txt?

The current platform is Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that Cmake cannot locate `llvm-config`. To fix this, one must point Cmake to the location of the program.

You will need to write a CMakeLists.txt like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

message(STATUS "Found LLVM ${LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_DIR}")

execute_process(COMMAND llvm-config --libs core  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${LLVM_TOOLS_BINARY_DIR} OUTPUT_VARIABLE x)
message(${x})
```

The `find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)` makes LLVM specific Cmake variables available.

To use `llvm-config` it is necessary to set the working directory  to`${LLVM_TOOLS_BINARY_DIR}`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/execute_process.html) function.

In your case :

```
execute_process(COMMAND llvm-config --libs core OUTPUT_VARIABLE x)
message(${x})
```

[`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/execute_process.html) have a lot of useful options, take a look at the doc.

Comment: I get error: "CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (message):
  message called with incorrect number of arguments"

Comment: The `execute_command()` cannot find the `llvm-config` command, which is seen from CMD. How do I solve this?

Comment: Quotes aroung `llvm-config` invocation string are not needed: command name and every command parameter should be **separate argument** from the sence of CMake.